# Synonym für „bessere Nutzung“

Tags: single-word-request, synonym

Womit kann man im folgenden Satz die *bessere Nutzung* ersetzen, oder ist die Formulierung in diesem Satz okay? *Verbesserung* passt hier nicht.

> Smart Mobility bezeichnet die bessere Nutzung vorhandener Infrastruktur durch die Gewinnung von Informationen aus moderner Kommunikationstechnik.

Comment: Das scheint in Ordnung zu sein.

Comment: *die effizientere Nutzung* ?

Comment: *Höhere Auslastung* ?

Answer (score 1):

Smart Mobility bezeichnet den *effizienteren Einsatz* vorhandener Infrastruktur durch die Gewinnung von Informationen aus moderner Kommunikationstechnik.